# App crashes when JSON value is null

Tags: java, android, json

I have a **jsonArray**, When the array is null, i got a crash saying **`app stopped unfortunately`**. But I want to show a text if the array is null. How can I do this? Got stuck in this problem last two days. **JSON** array is here:

```
[{"head_name":null,"amount":null,"vat":null,"for_month":null,"status":null}]
```

Here is my java code:

```
String url_payment_jul = Config.PAYMENT_JUL_URL+"?reference="+Config.userInfo.get(5);
    JsonArrayRequest req_jul = new JsonArrayRequest(url_payment_jul,
            new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONArray response_jul) {
                    Log.d("my data", response_jul.toString());

                    try {
                        // Parsing json array response
                        // loop through each json object
                        String jsonResponse = "";
                        for (int i = 0; i < response_jul.length(); i++) {

                            JSONObject paymentInfo_jul = (JSONObject)response_jul.get(i);

                            Config.paymentInfo_jul.add( paymentInfo_jul.getString("amount"));// Amount_jul in index (0)
                            Config.paymentInfo_jul.add( paymentInfo_jul.getString("vat"));// VAT_jul in index (1)
                            Config.paymentInfo_jul.add( paymentInfo_jul.getString("status"));// Status_jul in index (2)
                        }

                        String status_jul = Config.paymentInfo_jul.get(2);

                        if (status_jul == null){
                            textView_status_jul.setText(" Not Paid");

                        }else {
                            fixedAmount_jul();
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                "Error: " + e.getMessage(),
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            VolleyLog.d(",y error", "Error: " + error.getMessage());
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

Comment: show me  the Json when array is null

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
paymentInfo_jul.isNull("head_name")
```

https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html#isNull%28java.lang.String%29

```
    Config.paymentInfo_jul.add( paymentInfo_jul.isNull("amount")?"N/A":paymentInfo_jul.getString("amount"));// Amount_jul in index (0)
    Config.paymentInfo_jul.add(paymentInfo_jul.isNull("vat")?"N/A":paymentInfo_jul.getString("vat"));// VAT_jul in index (1)
    Config.paymentInfo_jul.add(paymentInfo_jul.isNull("status")?"Not Paid":paymentInfo_jul.getString("status"));// VAT_jul in index (2)
```

Or this can be simplified further using `optString` function

> Get an optional string associated with a key. It returns the
>   defaultValue if there is no such key.
>
> ```
>  public String optString(String key, String defaultValue) {
> ```

```
  Config.paymentInfo_jul.add( paymentInfo_jul.optString("amount","N/A"));
 // will return "N/A" if value is not or not found
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this Snippet:

```
if(response_jul.toString().equals("Null")){
   Log.i("jsa","null");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Config.paymentInfo_jul.add(paymentInfo_jul.getString("amount") == null ? YOUR_DEFAULT_VALUE : paymentInfo_jul.getString("amount"));
```

Answer (score 0):

For these problem you must use ladder of try and catch code let in your code ,

```
try{
    String status_jul = Config.paymentInfo_jul.get(2);
fixedAmount_jul();                            
textView_status_jul.setText(" Not Paid");

   }catch {
   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Error: " + e.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
           }
}
```

And in your for loop ,

```
try
{
 JSONObject paymentInfo_jul = (JSONObject) response_jul
                                    .get(i);

                            Config.paymentInfo_jul.add( paymentInfo_jul.getString("amount"));// Amount_jul in index (0)
                            Config.paymentInfo_jul.add( paymentInfo_jul.getString("vat"));// VAT_jul in index (1)
                            Config.paymentInfo_jul.add( paymentInfo_jul.getString("status"));// Status_jul in index (2)
}
catch(Exception e)
{
       Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Error: " + e.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}
```

And At every place where you are using if and else use try catch instead of if and else .

Answer (score 0):

solved my problem by doing this:

```
 if (status_jul.equals("null")){
                        textView_status_jul.setText(" Not Paid");

                    }else {
                        fixedAmount_jul();
                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

First make a textview on your xml layout that shows the text when jsonarray is null,with visibility as GONE

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/empty_view"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="You have no new  notifications"
        android:visibility="gone" />
```

On your onResponse() method,before applying the for loop, check the length of your array and if the length is 0,make the visibility of the textview as visible like

```
if(response_jul.length()==0){
emptyView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}else{
 for (int i = 0; i < response_jul.length(); i++) {

                            JSONObject paymentInfo_jul = (JSONObject) response_jul
                                    .get(i);

                            Config.paymentInfo_jul.add( paymentInfo_jul.getString("amount"));// Amount_jul in index (0)
                            Config.paymentInfo_jul.add( paymentInfo_jul.getString("vat"));// VAT_jul in index (1)
                            Config.paymentInfo_jul.add( paymentInfo_jul.getString("status"));// Status_jul in index (2)
                        }


                        String status_jul = Config.paymentInfo_jul.get(2);

                        if (status_jul == null){
                            textView_status_jul.setText(" Not Paid");

                        }else {
                            fixedAmount_jul();
                        }

}
```